# In the new office 365 word addins is there any way to access smart art objects

Tags: typescript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I've been using the script lab add-in to test various bits of code, and I can't work out how to access these components.  The code that I've managed to cobble together shows images (though I'm getting errors with getting the base64 source for them, but I'll work that out).

Below is the gist that I created for this test. It can be found on github here - https://gist.github.com/PhoenixStoneham/4525d1a994ab92c973a2b060974ff48c

Can anyone help me access these components?

To use this gist create a new document in msword and add some text (typing *=rand(2,4)* and pressing enter will create random text), then add a smartart object using the insert tab.  You can also add an image using the pictures option on the same tab.

```
name: Content control basics
description: 'Inserts, updates, and retrieves content controls.'
host: WORD
api_set: {}
script:
  content: |
    $("#insert-paragraph").click(() => insertParagraph());
    async function insertParagraph() {
      await Word.run(async function(context) {
        var explorer = new DocumentExplorer(context);
        await explorer.setup();
        explorer.CheckAllParagraphs();
        updateStatus('document controls ' + JSON.stringify(context.document.contentControls));
        updateStatus('body controls ' + JSON.stringify(context.document.body.contentControls));
      }).catch(function(error) {
        updateStatus("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
          updateStatus("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        };
      });
    }
    // Create a function for writing to the status div.
    function updateStatus(message: string) {
      console.log(message);
    }
    class DocumentExplorer {
      context: Word.RequestContext;
      document: Word.Document;
      officeDocument: Office.Document;
      sections: Word.SectionCollection;
      allparagraphs: Word.ParagraphCollection;
      body: Word.Body;
      constructor(context: Word.RequestContext) {
        this.context = context;
        this.document = context.document;
        this.officeDocument = Office.context.document;
        this.sections = this.document.sections;
      }
      public async setup() {
        this.allparagraphs = this.document.body.paragraphs;
        this.allparagraphs.load();
        await this.update();
        this.allparagraphs.items.forEach( (paragraph) => {
          paragraph.inlinePictures.load();
          paragraph.contentControls.load();
        });
        return this.context.sync();
      }
      public async CheckAllParagraphs() {
        this.allparagraphs.items.forEach( async (paragraph) => {
         await this.CheckParagraph(paragraph);
        });
      }
      public async CheckParagraph(paragraph: Word.Paragraph) {
        updateStatus("Loading controls and images");
        var controls = paragraph.contentControls;
        var images = paragraph.inlinePictures;
        updateStatus(JSON.stringify(paragraph));
        updateStatus("There are " + controls.items.length + " controls");
        controls.items.forEach( (item) => {
          item.load();
        });
          await this.update();
        updateStatus("There are " + images.items.length + " images");
        images.items.forEach((image) => {
          image.load();
          var src =image.getBase64ImageSrc();
           this.context.sync().then((result)=>{console.log(src.value);});
          
        });
        return this.context.sync();
      }
      public async update() {
        await this.context.sync().catch((reason) => {
          updateStatus(JSON.stringify(reason));
          if (reason instanceof Error) {
            var e: Error = reason;
            updateStatus(e.message);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  language: typescript
template:
  content: "<section class=\"ms-font-m\">\n\tThis sample demonstrates how to insert and change content control properties.\n</section>\n\n<section class=\"samples ms-font-m\">\n\t<h3>Try it out</h3>\n\n\t<button class=\"ms-Button\" id=\"insert-paragraph\">Insert Paragraph</button><br /><br />\n</section>"
  language: html
style:
  content: |-
    section.samples {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    section.samples .ms-Button, section.setup .ms-Button {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        min-width: 80px;
    }
  language: css
libraries: |-
  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js
  @types/office-js
  office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.min.css
  office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css
  core-js@2.4.1/client/core.min.js
  @types/core-js
  jquery@3.1.1
  @types/jquery@3.3.1
```

Comment: Please give more detail about what you expect to see then the snippet runs and what you actually see.

Comment: I expect to see a console statement indicating the shape that is a smartart object, as well as the json for that object. It works fine for images, but doesn't work for content controls, so I don't know if they will show the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Currently only Rich Content Controls are supported in the Office JavaScript library. See [Word.ContentControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview).

To work with SmartArt, I think you have to work at the level of OOXML. See [Create better add-ins ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml?view=word-js-preview).